# Receiving - Ledger Application level error (sign-with-hash) - on Endorsements

Tags: baking, ledger

Full error message is -

`Ledger Application level error (sign-with-hash): Security status unsatisfied - The operation was automatically rejected for security reasons. If baking, you may need to setup the device or reset the high-water mark.`

I've reset my highwater mark, but still gives me that error message. I'm on v11 and my Ledger is 2.2.13.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is indicated in the last sentence.
You need to run

```
tezos-client setup ledger to bake for <alias>
```

you can set a High-Water-Mark by appending

```
--main-hwm <HWM>
```

HWM can be the current Blockheight, or any block higher than your last bake or endorsement.